# Transformation of function mixed with modulus function

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm confused about the order of transformation of f(x) to f(|x|-2). Why should we transform the graph to the right first and then deal with the modulus instead of dealing with "bracket" || first and then transform horizontally?

Comment: I would definitely deal with the absolute value first, and then worry about the horizontal shift. Who is telling you otherwsie?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Trying it with $f(x) = x,$ if I do the modulus first I get a corner at $(0,0),$ then shift right to $(2,0)$ resulting in a $y$-intercept of $2.$ But the $y$-intercept of $f(|x|-2)$ is $f(|0|-2)=-2.$

Answer (score 0):

If you do as you suggest, i.e. the modulus transformation followed by the translation, as a sequence it would be

$$f(x)\rightarrow f(|x|)\rightarrow f(|x-2|)$$
which is obviously not the expression you want.

On the other hand, with the translation first followed by the modulus transformation, the sequence would be

$$f(x)\rightarrow f(x-2)\rightarrow f(|x|-2)$$

Comment: I see it the other way, $f(x)$ becomes $f(|x|)$ becomes $f(|x|-2)$.